# The server was not found or was not accessible

Tags: sql-server

Recently my friend gave me a project which is made of vb.net and sql server 2000.

When I open it the software first loads the welcome screen but after that an error pops up which has a label of microsoft.net framework and inside it the error is:

> "Unhandled exception has occurred in your application.If you click continue the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. A network related or instance specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is "

I am using SQL Server 2005 Express edition. Please explain to me how to resolve, step-by-step and in detail. It will be a great help to me, thank you.

Comment: did you "Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is running"? What was the outcome? Check the web.config to find the connection string to your  sqlserver..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application connection strings are pointing to a SQL server that doesn't exist in your environment.

Check the application config file and correct the connection string.

Comment: Hey please can you explain me in detail since I am not able to understand it...I have sql 2005 express edition installed

Comment: @FrozenKing - The application needs to connect to a database. It knows what database/server to connect to by using a connection string. This connection string will include the name of the SQL server and database (as well as other information needed for the connection). Normally the connection string is stored in the .config file of the application. If the information is incorrect, your application will not be able to use the database. This is very basic.

Comment: so is their a problem with the application??or do I have to install some other sql versions?thanks

Comment: @FrozenKing - You need to make sure the connection string in the configuration matches the settings on your SQL Server.

Comment: is their any problem with the application or in my pc sql is not been installed correctly

Comment: ohkk last i got the configuration file but what should I do to it?

Comment: @FrozenKing - Make sure the server,database name and all other values on the connection string element are corresponding to how you set up your SQL Server instance.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check connection string to SQL server. Usually it stored in configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

You have to verify that you are connected to the server. If the server has an instance like `server\\sqlexpress`, then you have to provide the instance also. Only then will it allow you.

Comment: how to verify?please explain me step by step